# Pass ID from React to Apollo to find correct result?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

Im using React with Apollo (Apollo Client v2). I have group query which needs to return a single group.

This code is working but I've hard coded `HARD-CODED-ID`. How can I instead pass the ID as a string from the React component?

In my React component:

```
const groupQuery = gql`
    query Group {
        group {
            _id
            name
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(groupQuery, {
    props: ({ data }) => ({ ...data }),
})(GroupPage);
```

My resolver:

```
Query: {
    groups() {
        return Groups.find().fetch();
    },
    group() {
        return Groups.findOne('HARD-CODED-ID');
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three things that you'll need to do:

1.) If you haven't already, modify the schema on your server so that your query accepts the id as an input, for example:

```
type Query {
  #other queries
  group(id: ID!): Group
}
```

2.) Modify your resolver so that it handles the passed-in id. Assuming you're using `graphql-tools`:

```
group(root, { id }) {
  return Groups.findOne(id); // did you mean something like findOne({id}) ?
},
```

3.) Modify your client-side code. Typically, you'll make the id a prop you pass in to your component, and then use that as a variable in your request.

```
const groupQuery = gql`
    query Group($id: ID!) {
        group(id: $id) {
            _id
            name
        }
    }
`;

// assuming that the component prop is called groupId
export default graphql(groupQuery, {
    options: ({ groupId }) => ({
      variables: { id: groupId },
    }),
})(GroupPage);
```

Instead of an object, options can be a function, in which case it's passed the component's props as its first parameter. You can then use those props to define the variables your query will use. You can read more about using variables with Apollo client [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-options) and [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-variables).

Comment: IM getting some errors: modules.js http://localhost:3000/graphql 400 (Bad Request) and Unhandled (in react-apollo:Apollo(GroupPage)) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Comment: Ive put a console.log in the resolver for root and id so I know what is being passed. Im getting undefined and an empty object.

Comment: Im trying to work though it step by step. Im using the Graphiql interface so I know its not a React issue. What is the syntax to pass a parameter from Graphiql? {
  group(_id:"dfd") {
   name
  }
 }

Comment: Sorry! Just needed to rebuild my server and refresh the GraphiQL page.